# Android : How to check difference between click , longclick and swipe in terms of timestamp and coordinates of X and Y in pixels?

Tags: android, click, swipe

I am developing a parser of the result of command : adb shell getevent -lt in python and I am checking when we pressed if we have one click, long click or swipe. To do that, I am checking the difference between the first timestamp and the last timestamp and difference between the first coordinates and maj of coordinates of X and Y in pixels. I would have some documentation about the limits of difference between first timestamp and last timestamp.

For example , if difference between 0 and 0.5 second we can say that we have a simple click, if difference between 0.5 and 1 second we can say that we have a long click , etc....
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source of the GestureDetector class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#GestureDetector), the timeouts are:

```
private static final int LONGPRESS_TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout();
private static final int TAP_TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout();
private static final int DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout();
private static final int DOUBLE_TAP_MIN_TIME = ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapMinTime();
```

If you dig a little further you can find that for android 5.1, the numbers are:

- Long press: 500ms
- Tap timeout: 100ms
- Double tap timeout: 300ms
- Double tap min time: 40ms

Source: [ViewConfigration](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#ViewConfiguration.0TAP_TIMEOUT)

Comment: Thank you for your reply . However  I am working on Android 4.4.4

Comment: The numbers are the same between 4.4.4 and 5.1